# CSS - Applying borders and padding to responsive (%-based) grid systems

Tags: html, css

I'm field testing ZURB's [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and wanted to know if there's an elegant solution to applying borders and padding to divs in the grid, without breaking it or resorting to: 1) Custom classes with reduced widths/margins, 2) Embedding an extra non-grid `<div>` in the parent, grid-based `<div>`

I've also tried `{ box-sizing: border-box; }` but mobile browsers don't seem to abide.

Suggestions? Thanks people!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using outlines instead of borders - the shorthand is exactly the same, but it does not impact the box model.